Packages not recognizing the current version of node when installing form-js
I am trying to npm install the packages of bpmn.io's form-js and it is stated in the docs that the requirements are node 16 and npm 8. So I used nvm to change my node and npm version to the ones required. Now I use node -v and npm -v and their results are:
v16.20.2
8.19.4

But after running npm install, it seems like it still assumes my node is 12:
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'minimatch@9.0.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16 || 14 >=14.17' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'styled-components@6.1.11',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'rollup-plugin-css-only@4.5.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

I have tried cleaning the cache after version switch:
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json

I also tried ensuring the PATH environment variable is correctly set to use the nvm-installed version of Node:
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" bash_completion


But still, even after reboot, it seems like there's something wrong. Here's the rest of the errors in case someone recognizes what is wrong:
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'rollup-plugin-css-only@4.5.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated read-package-json@6.0.4: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.
npm WARN deprecated read-package-json@7.0.1: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@6.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated are-we-there-yet@3.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated gauge@4.0.4: This package is no longer supported.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/okaeiz/Camunda/form-js/node_modules/nx
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node ./bin/post-install
npm ERR! /home/okaeiz/Camunda/form-js/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/project-graph.js:119
npm ERR!         ...(projectConfigurationsError?.errors ?? []),
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
npm ERR!     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/okaeiz/Camunda/form-js/node_modules/nx/bin/post-install.js:3:25)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-06T08_08_02_495Z-debug-0.log


I think the nvm node isn't been used. Did you miss something in your nvm setup? What is the output of running npm config get prefix in your terminal? Also what does running which npm return.

@OluwafemiSule The output of npm config get prefix is /home/okaeiz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2. And the output of which npm is /home/okaeiz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm which seems okay. But the installation keeps failing.

What does nvm current yield?

@OluwafemiSule Command nvm current yields v16.20.2

I just checked this issue on another machine. It still assumes I am using node v12!

After countless hours of hairpulling effort, I found out that this is a connection problem. I tried to run npm install while connected to a proxy and the packages were installed successfully.
Regarding the deprecation warnings and the Node and npm incompatibility, I realized those were irrelevant errors and you can safely ignore them.
